# How to change Locale in MinGW

Tags: c++, windows-10, mingw

It seems like only the "C" locale is working with MinGW. I tried the [example found here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/locale/locale) and no commas were added even though the system locale is set to Canada.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <locale>

int main()
{
    std::wcout << "User-preferred locale setting is " << std::locale("").name().c_str() << '\n';
    // on startup, the global locale is the "C" locale
    std::wcout << 1000.01 << '\n';
    // replace the C++ global locale as well as the C locale with the user-preferred locale
    std::locale::global(std::locale(""));
    // use the new global locale for future wide character output
    std::wcout.imbue(std::locale());
    // output the same number again
    std::wcout << 1000.01 << '\n';
}
```

The output is

```
User-preferred locale setting is C
100000
100000
```

I tried `std::locale("en-CA")` and get `locale::facet::_S_create_c_locale name not valid` at run time. I compile from CMD using g++. I'm running 64bit Windows 10.

Also I tried compiling this program found in the accepted answer here and got the compiler error `'LOCALE_ALL' was not declared in this scope`.

How can I set the locale in MinGW to the system default or something explicit?